# лишние срабатывания функции внутри функции

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста почему в коде:

```
let n=0,
    m=0 
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  n++
  $('#button2').on('click', function(){
    m++
  })
})
```

Переменная **m** будет увеличиваться каждый раз как я нажму на **#button**, хотя на **#button2** я не нажимаю
Вот [пример](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rXWvBJ) в песочнице. Если я например 4 раза нажму кнопку1, не нажимая кнопку2, то счетчик выведет "кнопка1: 4", но если я после этого нажму кнопка2, то счетчик для этой кнопки выведет не значение 1, как я думал, потому что это первое ее нажатие, а учтет все предыдущие нажатия по кнопке1, то есть выведет 4.

**UPD:** Спасибо за пояснения по происходящему. Тогда у меня вопрос. Есть ли возможность не запускать действия вложенной функции при запуске родительской функции? В моем проекте пользователь вызывает форму, но он может воспользоваться одним функционалом (нажатие на кнопку1 из примера выше), а может другим (нажатие на кнопку1, *а затем* на кнопку2). Мне бы хотелось, чтобы *не нажимая* на кнопку2, переменная **m** не увеличивалась, как происходит сейчас в песочнице. Ну или как-то сбрасывать количество вызовов функции.
Надеюсь, понятно объяснил

Comment: Потому что вы добавляете обработчик клика button2 каждый раз во время клика на button1. Если вы кликнете button1 четыре раза, вы тем самым добавите ЧЕТЫРЕ обработчика клика button2, и последующий клик на button2 обработается ЧЕТЫРЬМЯ обработчиками с соответствующим результатом

Comment: так ведь условия запуска вложенной функции `$('#button2').on('click', function()` НАЖАТИЕ на кнопку. Если я не нажимаю на кнопку, то все условия внутри функции все равно выполняются?

Comment: Ну вы ж сами написали «я после этого нажму кнопка2». Когда вы её нажимаете, срабатывают четыре ранее добавленных вами обработчика, которые вы добавили ранее, строчка `m++` выполняется четыре раза в чётырёх обработчиках, и вы в итоге видите число 4

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я думал что обработчики срабатывают здесь и сейчас и не запоминают сколько раз их вешали. Видимо страдает матчасть. Уточню свой вопрос

Comment: а зачем одна функция внутри другой навешивается, не понятно

Comment: зачем делать так: `$('#button').on('click', function(){
  n++
  $('#button2').on('click', function(){
    m++
  })
})` если можно делать так: `$('#button').on('click', function(){
  n++
});   $('#button2').on('click', function(){
    m++
  })
`

Comment: я немного изменил пример в песочнице. Если я нажму _начать покупку_ и _отменить покупку_ несколько раз, не выбирая товар (карандаши и ручки). А затем все таки выберу товар, он посчитает все предыдущие нажатия, а также выведет оповещение "покупка совершена" не 1 раз, а несколько

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сбросить навешанные обработчики событий использовал метод `.unbind`. То есть, следующий код

```
let n=0,
    m=0 
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  n++
  $('#button2').unbind('click')
  $('#button2').on('click', function(){
    m++
    console.log('button2-'+m)
  })
console.log('button-'+n)
})
```

позволит считать отдельно нажатие на первую кнопку и отдельно на вторую благодаря строке

```
$('#button2').unbind('click')
```

Выглядит как костыль, но для моей задачи подошло, может еще кому пригодится.

**UPD**: Также можно использовать метод *.off()*

```
$('#button2').off('click')
```

Comment: вместо [`unbind`](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) лучше [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) для однообразия с on и потому что с 3 версии этот метод считается устаревшим

Comment: Grundy, спасибо, дополню ответ